# Can't create outlet using Interface Builder - Lock symbol shown

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, xcode4.4

I'm trying to create outlets using the Interface Builder, however when drag the UILabel from the IB to my controller's .h file the big lock symbol flashes for a few seconds and it doesn't actually create the bind between the UILabel and the outlet (although the code *is* generated). I also noticed an empty circle is created by this new definition. When it worked, a filled in circle was created on the side).

I've checked the UILabel and all parent views and have checked that their "Lock" property is set to "Inherit (Nothing)" (and have even set them all to "Nothing").

In the IB the UILabel doesn't show the "x" that appear when a UILabel is locked either.

So I have no idea if I'm missing to unlock something, or what I'm doing wrong to be able to create this outlet.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using a custom view controller, and I'm using this same view controller subclass for 2 different view controllers in the same storyboard. I had no problems creating outlets this way for the first view controller.

Tryed reopening XCode (using 4.4.1) with no luck.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So are you dragging both UILabels from each View Controller into the same file? I don't think that this is possible, on the second view controller, try to Ctrl drag to the file owner within the IB view, that is, assuming that both views are connected to the same instance.
Also, in your identity tab in storyboard, under Localization Locked, make sure your storyboard locked setting is set to default as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169636/720175

Comment: I'm using a storyboard in which I have 2 scenes. Both use the same custom view controller (defined as CalculationsViewController : UIViewController). For the first scene I was able to drag the UILabels and create Outlets with no problem. For the second I'm unable to, and the scene UILabels and other elements appear to be locked, even though I have checked all over and parents seem unlocked. Since I'm using a storyboard, how do I drag to the file owner from IB? If I'm not mistaken, the icon is not present. PS I'm seeing this "locked" status in the first scene as well :S

Comment: Okay, I'm guessing that you are using the split screen view to drag the connections, are you using the same connections on each view(i.e. same UILabels, etc)?

Comment: Yep, I'm using the split screen view and from the IB, dragging the UILabels to the .h file. Each scene has it's own UILabels. I was able to drag the first scene's UILabels over to the .h file and the outlets were created fine. That was about 1 or 2 weeks ago and I completed the coding for scene 1. Now I was going to start the coding for scene 2, started dragging the UILabels of this scene, but I'm getting this weirdness. Weird thing is now I'm getting the "locked" status from UILabels of scene 1 as well, even though all parent views are not locked for either scene.

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen this problem before. So the class for both views are set to the same class right? I think that you aren't able to drag connections when two or more views point to the same class. Try declaring the `IBOutlets` and then connect them by dragging to the `File's Owner` rather than using the split screen view.

Comment: I also get the lock icon flash for a few seconds.

Comment: I tried created a new subclass but I'm getting the same lock symbol when I drag the UILabel. Is there any other way I could have locked the scene?

Comment: Thanks for your time Michael. Would you like to edit your answer to include the above?

Comment: Yes, I think there is a way you can lock the entire storyboard. Check your storyboard identity. Did my answer work for you? If so, please mark as accepted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30100/discussion-between-rob-and-michaelscaria)

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a totally new scene and would also get the lock symbol. So it wasn't only the scenes, but the whole storyboard. So a quick search on SO lead me to the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169636/720175