# Xcode has locked the views and controls and can't edit them

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

I've pulled the project from Git. Someone else was working on it and it works perfectly fine for them, they can edit every control and every constraint. On mine I can only edit what I have added, the controls which were already there are locked (grayed out on the image.)

I tried clicking the **lock** icon on the preview screen and it says this:

```
“Main.storyboard” is currently locked because it is a remote resource.
```

and when clicking **Unlock**

```
The file is a remote resource. Try making a local copy.
```

Literally have no idea what to do now. I've tried **Editor->Localization Locking->Reset Locking Controls** to no avail.

If I cut and then paste a locked control back into the scene, it works fine but I loose all the constraints previously set on it and it all needs to be rearranged again so it's more of an observation not a solution.

Comment: hi did you see this post if you not seen then have look :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998834/xcode-storyboard-wont-accept-changes

Comment: Tried it before, didn't work. It seems like maybe because it was pulled from a repository it sees the file as a remote file, even though it is saved on the local disk

Comment: yes may be as you saying..also i had seen this post :

https://pragmapilot.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/xcode-5-interface-builder-storyboard-locked/

Comment: Have you tried switching size classes? I think you must try switching between size classes may be the views are added to specific size class only so they are greyed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the controls were added to a different size class, that's why they are grayed out. You can verify this by selecting the grayed out object in the storyboard and in the attribute inspector you can check in what size classes is enabled. For example in the image is enabled just for Any width and Compact height, but not for Any-Any. You can add/remove the control to a different size class by checking/unchecking it.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant spot! Thanks for this!